# Converting an ElasticBeanstalk environment to a Docker container

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, docker, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running several Ruby applications in Elasticbeanstalk in AWS.

I'd like developers to have the ability to run this applications locally in Docker containers.

However, the Ruby applications have never been run anywhere other than in Beanstalk, so I haven't inherited any documentation re. how they are deployed.

Beanstalk itself uses Passenger Standalone running on Amazon Linux. The applications are configured by passing "Environment Properties" into the environment from the the Beanstalk configuration.

Has anyone attempted this or something similar before?

I'm hoping that its just a matter of running an Amazon Linux Docker container with Passenger Standalone, setting up the environment variables, and dropping the Ruby code into the correct directory, but I suspect it will be more complex than this.

Comment: Have you tried ruby onbuild docker image? [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/)

Comment: Yes, I can run the application in the passenger image provided by phusion, but for the developers to feel confident, they like a closer approximation to Beanstalk.

From what I can see the the eb-activity.log in Beanstalk instances that run Rails apps, the setup is highly convoluted, so this may not be a runner.